# Implement chat heads like Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, chat, facebook-android-sdk

I want to implement chat heads like facebook does.

[image]

I have tried custom notification but i haven't get any success yet.
Please tell me if anyone have idea for implementing chat heads like this.

Answer (score 5):

Here you can find a nice eloboration on how to achieve want you are looking for:
http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/

Comment: And the site is down, making this answer invalid. You should have at least posted some code snippets.

Comment: It's strange: when clicking the link from StackOverflow it's broken. If you copy the exact same link and paste it to your browser it's still working - I've no idea why.
Posting a code snippet wouldn't be sufficient in that case cause the blog post features a comprehensive elaboration on that topic which could not be broken down into a few lines of code.

Comment: The  URL is not valid. Please update it or delete the Answer.